# How to console.log the data properly with fetch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

What's the proper way of returning the data not the promise object as the code snippet below does?

```js
const getData = async () => {  
  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
    const data = res.json();
    return data; 
  } catch (error) {
    ToastAndroid.show(error, ToastAndroid.LONG);
  }
};
    
console.log(getGeneralData());
```

Comment: Since [`Body.prototype.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) still returns a Promise, you’d want `await res.json()` in any case.

Comment: It still returns a promise

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: As Sebastian mentioned, you need `const data = await res.json();`

Comment: @MikeWazowksi Your question says `getGeneralData()`. Did you mean `getData()` here? In any case, I don’t think you have a choice here. `.then` can only be avoided inside an `async` function (or globally if the engine supports [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) and the JS is in a module). Alternatively, you could use `(async () => { console.log(await getData()); })();`.

Answer (score 0):

Async Functions return a promise, you need to use :

```
getData().then(res=>console.log(res);
```

Comment: But isn't using async and await is to avoid the usage of then()?

Comment: By making getData() async, you are making getData asynchronous and allowing the usage of 'await' inside its scope. However console.log() is outside the async scope, you cant use await keyword with it.

however, if your console.log() is inside an async function you can do console.log(await getData());

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in "self invoked" function `(async function() {....})()` and it allows you to use `await` for awaiting result of `getData()`.

```js
(async function() {
  const getData = async() => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
      const data = res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      ToastAndroid.show(error, ToastAndroid.LONG);
    }
  };

  console.log(await getData());
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `async` function is just syntactic sugar for a `Promise`. You can call the `.then()` method to handle resolving the promise.

```js
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments';

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    ToastAndroid.show(error, ToastAndroid.LONG);
  }
};

getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```